# Some way to "embed" a script to download/delete a file whithin a web server?

Tags: nginx, web-server, bash, scripting

I need to make a server work this way:

Check if the requested file exists locally.

- if is there, serve it right away
- if not, pass the REQUEST_URI to a script which will download it
- if the file has ?delete=1, call the script to remove it

I had successfully implemented this behavior with nginx (using the 404 error handler) and PHP.
The thing is that to implement this on another server I have to install/compile both nginx and php.

My question is if there is a way to remove php from the stack and put up nginx (or some other server) to do the job. An ideal way for me would be if I could run/call bash scripts/commands directly from the server.

Does anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished with plain ol' CGI and a shell script very easily.  How you enable/implement CGI depends on the server.  Nginx *should* be capable, but I know Apache is.  Refer to the documentation or ask a specific question about enabling CGI on a given web server.

Simple bash logic to test for a whether a file exists and display it:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/path/to/file"
URI="http://example.com/file"

/bin/echo "Content-type: text/plain"
/bin/echo

if [ -f $FILE ]; then
  /bin/cat $FILE
else
  /usr/bin/wget $URI
fi
```

You can parse ${QUERY_STRING} to get your delete action.  I'll leave the full solution and error handling as an exercise to you.  It gets a little tricky and is beyond the scope of our Q&A format.

See: [Parsing of QUERY_STRING in Bash CGI Scripts](http://marc.waeckerlin.org/computer/blog/parsing_of_query_string_in_bash_cgi_scripts)

Comment: Thank me with your upvote and an accepted answer if it ends up working for you. :)